# Verificacion con validator.w3

Tags: html

Estoy trabajando en una pagina y cuando la paso por el validator me salta errores los cuales no se como solucionar.
Alguien que entienda esa pagina me podria ayudar?
Aqui les dejo unos ejemplos de lo que me sale.
Muchas gracias
[image: ejemplos]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad. Adicional seria bueno que colocaras los errores que te salen

Comment: Hola mauro, podrías especificar los errores que te aparecen, tal vez mostrar por medio de capturas de pantalla a la hora de ejecutar el validator, o alguna forma que podamos ver los errores? Muchas gracias!